# How to get StreamSubscription from StreamBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

When adding a listener to a RxDart `PublishSubject` I get a `StreamSubscription`. I can then use the `StreamSubscription` to pause and resume, is there any way to do that with a `StreamBuilder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You cannot pause listening to a `Stream` using `StreamBuilder`. If you want to, you will have to manually subscribe to your `Stream` and call `pause` yourself.